# How to block out dates in the Fullcalendar beyond a certain date

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, fullcalendar

I have a date in the future which is always 30 days ahead of the current date. It's stored in a Date object. I worked this out using:

```
var currentDate = new Date();
var futureBlockDate = new Date();
futureBlockDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 30);
```

Using the [FullCalendar jQuery plugin](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) I want to visually block out any days past this date on the calendar with a different background colour so a user knows they can't click on them or create an event on those days.

What is the best way to do this with the FullCalendar? Maybe disable all dates by default, and only enable for a specific range (from today's date through to 30 days in the future)?

I think I can apply a disabled background state to all the cells using the following code:

```
$(".fc-widget-content").addClass("disabled");

.disabled .fc-day-content {
    background-color: #123959;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    cursor: default;
}
```

How can it be done?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use the [dayRender](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/display/dayRender/) option to add a "disabled" class to out of range dates.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    ...
    dayRender: function(date, cell){
        if (date > maxDate){
            $(cell).addClass('disabled');
        }
    }
    ...
});
```

You can also use the [viewRender](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/display/viewRender/) event and the [gotoDate](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/current_date/gotoDate/) method, to prevent users to navigate farther than 30 days after today :

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    ...
    viewRender: function(view){
        if (view.start > maxDate){
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', maxDate);
        }
    }
    ...
});
```

Comment: does this block click or drag events in this area?

Comment: this solution works just for month, basicWeek, and basicDay views :)

Comment: in FullCalendar v4, you can do it directly using the validRange option in calendar properties. Please see Sajid Ali Khan's answer below.

Answer (score 6):

[How about this solution?](http://jsfiddle.net/watson/7MTdn/267/)

```
dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
   var myDate = new Date();

   //How many days to add from today?
   var daysToAdd = 15;

   myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + daysToAdd);

   if (date < myDate) {
       //TRUE Clicked date smaller than today + daysToadd
       alert("You cannot book on this day!");
   } else {
       //FLASE Clicked date larger than today + daysToadd
       alert("Excellent choice! We can book today..");
   }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

In new version V4 of Full Calendar, there are lot of updates and you can find the settings for your need

***Limits which dates the user can navigate to and where events can go.***

```
// constrain to a discrete range
var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
  defaultView: 'dayGridMonth',
  validRange: {
    start: '2017-05-01',
    end: '2017-06-01'
  }
});

// constrain to an open-ended range
var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
  defaultView: 'dayGridMonth',
  validRange: {
    start: '2017-05-01'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

For someone who is looking for a solution to define a `min-display-date` and `max-display-date`: (for fullcalendar v2)

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultDate: new Date(),
    viewRender: function(view, element) {

        curdate = new Date();
        viewdate = new Date(view.start);

        // PREV - force minimum display month to current month
        if (new Date(viewdate.getFullYear(), viewdate.getMonth() + 1, 1).getTime() <= 
            new Date(curdate.getFullYear(), curdate.getMonth(), 1).getTime()){
            $('.fc-prev-button').prop('disabled', true);
            $('.fc-prev-button').css('opacity', 0.5);
        } else {
            $('.fc-prev-button').prop('disabled', false);
            $('.fc-prev-button').css('opacity', 1);
        }

        // NEXT - force max display month to a year from current month
        if (new Date(viewdate.getFullYear(), viewdate.getMonth() + 1).getTime() >= 
            new Date(curdate.getFullYear() + 1, curdate.getMonth() + 1).getTime()){
            $('.fc-next-button').prop('disabled', true);
            $('.fc-next-button').css('opacity', 0.5);
        } else {
            $('.fc-next-button').prop('disabled', false);
            $('.fc-next-button').css('opacity', 1);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

this one chose the current month period

```
<?php $numerodias = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, date('m'), date('Y')); ?>
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'today'
            },
            defaultDate: moment(),
            editable: false,
            //height:'auto',
            //weekends: false,
            defaultView: 'agendaWeek', 
            eventLimit: true, 

            events: {
                url: 'php/get-events.php',
                error: function() {
                    $('#script-warning').show();
                }

            },
            loading: function(bool) {
                $('#loading').toggle(bool);

            },
        viewRender: function(view,element) {
            var now = new Date();
            var end = new Date();
            end.setMonth(now.getMonth()); 
            end.setDate(<?php echo $numerodias; ?>);
            now.setDate(1);
            if ( end < view.end) {
                $("#calendar .fc-next-button").hide();
                return false;
                alert(end);
            }
            else {
                $("#calendar .fc-next-button").show();
            }

            if ( view.start < now) {
                $("#calendar .fc-prev-button").hide();
                return false;
            }
            else {
                $("#calendar .fc-prev-button").show();
            }
        }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

for disable cell on click (version 2.0) :

```
dayRender: function( date, cell ) {
     // It's an example, do your own test here
    if(cell.hasClass("fc-other-month")) {
          cell.addClass('disabled');
     } 

},
dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
    if($(jsEvent.target).hasClass("disabled")){
        return false;
    }
    // Your code
    // ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this code in Fullcalendar:

```
select: function (start, end, jsEvent, view) {
            if (start.isBefore(moment())) {
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
                return false;
            }
            else {

                 var currentDate = moment(start).format('YYYY/MM/DD'));
                 alert(currentDate);
            } 
        }
```

Simple and fast. Enjoy!