# Is it possible to block certain cell from adding event in fullcalendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, background-color

[image]

Hi everybody!

I'm using [fullcalendar jquery plugin](http://fullcalendar.io/download/) and I want to block some cell from adding events.
I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19670748) but I don't figure out how it works and what is the maxDate!

I want that the render is like the picture above (the white block with red border), but I didn't find the solution.

How can I do?

Comment: if your JS that add's events (or whatever code you use to add events) will need to test if the event falls in that range and now allow it.

Comment: I load events via ajax

Comment: ok, but how do you add events? or describe more how you want the "blocked cell" to work?

Comment: In a specific date, I want to block cell, then, if the user want to drap event upon that blocked cell, it will display an alert or something like that. I add events like this [way](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_function/)

Comment: Then you need to implement that in the eventDrop callback

Comment: Thanks for your help, I found the solution! :)

Comment: you should post your solution.

Comment: It's not a good solution, it is just for the moment! I'll post it

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution

I put an a new blocked property to the event. Then if blocked is true, I add a `backgroundColor` white, and set `start` and `end` date.

The following code is a simple algorythm

```
if ( events.blocked ) {
    // action goes here
    // compare the date ( using moment ) enter by the user with the blocked start or end date
    // if the date is between start and end event, i display an alert
    // then reload the original events
}
```

Comment: exactly what i put in the first comment to your question :)

Comment: yeah, I just follow what you did say! :)