# FullCalendar calendar start date

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am trying to disable previous days on my calender so select events aren't executed on those dates.

I've tried

```
  defaultDate: '2015-03-25',
  minDate: '2015-03-25',

  eventConstraint: {
    start: '2015-03-25'
  },
```

any one know how I can do this?

Thanks

UPDATE -- like this?

```
  viewRender: function(view){
          if (view.start < minDate){
              $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', minDate);
          }
      },
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19670748/how-to-block-out-dates-in-the-fullcalendar-beyond-a-certain-date

Comment: Thanks for the comment.. I've attempted to use viewRender and it doesn't work in my case.  I think I may be doing something wrong.  Please check my update.

Comment: @Goddard what do you mean so "select events aren't executed"? Do you mean that events aren't rendered, or that the person cannot click/select previous dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Disabling viewing of the past

Assuming the code you have in your `viewRender` update is the desired behaviour, it should be:

```
viewRender: function(view){
      if (view.start.isBefore(moment())){  //if view start is before now
          $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', moment); //go to now
      }
  },
```

Fullcalendar uses the [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/docs/) library for dates, so you can't use `<` to do a comparison.

[JSFiddle demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/slicedtoad/8auggxcm/1/)

But this is kinda weird behavior. Are you sure you don't want people to *see* the past? And what about when you are half way through a month?

### Limiting events to the present

Let's add some tweaks to make this more usable:

- Two [background events](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/Background_Events/), both covering the same dates (past to the current date/time). We need one as an all-day and one as a timed event since:

> Background events that are timed will only be rendered on the time
>   slots in agenda view. Background events that are all-day will only be
>   rendered in month view or the all-day slots of agenda view.
>
> [selectOverlap](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/selection/selectOverlap/) and [eventOverlap](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_ui/eventOverlap/) callbacks. These provide an easy way to stop the user from creating or moving events to the past.

```
events: [{ // All-day past
    id: 'past',
    start: '1900-01-01',
    end: moment(),
    rendering: 'background',
    allDay: true
}, { // Timed past
    id: 'past',
    start: '1900-01-01',
    end: moment(),
    rendering: 'background',
}, /*other event sources...*/ ],

// Disable selection on top of the "past" event
selectOverlap: function (event) {
    return event.id !== 'past';
},
// Disable dragging on top of the "past" event
eventOverlap: function (stillEvent, movingEvent) {
    return stillEvent.id !== 'past';
},
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/slicedtoad/8auggxcm/3/)