# How to set maximum and minimum date range in fullcalendar jquery

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

i am working in FullCalendar v2.2.5. i need to set max and min date in my full calender same as we do in datepicker.
Disable all those dates before min date and after max dates.
Please help me to sort out this issue.
Thanks in advance ..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19670748/how-to-block-out-dates-in-the-fullcalendar-beyond-a-certain-date

Answer (score 19):

For v3.3.1 for me works `validRange`

```
validRange: {
    start: '2017-05-01',
    end: '2017-06-01'
}
```

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/validRange

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultView: 'month',
    visibleRange: {
        start: '2017-03-22',
        end: '2017-03-25'
    }
});
```

This will make only the defined date range visible in full calendar. Just put your desired start and end date with in above piece of code.

Comment: thanks for the help, i tried but i need to disable the navigation buttons and i need it in monthly view.

Comment: Will you elaborate on the navigation you are encountering?

Comment: would you care to explain the downvote?
It helped the cause btw.