# Primefaces schedule disable past dates

Tags: primefaces, fullcalendar, schedule

I am using primefaces 8.0. I would like to disable past dates in schedule component. I just found minTime and maxTime. Can i use day change event?

Comment: PrimeFaces has the `extender` functionality on the `p:schedule`, allowing you to configure the underlying jquery fullcalendar in ways that is not possible with PrimeFaces attributes. Check the jquery fullcalendar documentation to see if it is possible.

Comment: I found this, but i dont know how can i use this code with extender: select: function(start, end, allDay) {
    var check = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start,'yyyy-MM-dd');
    var today = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(new Date(),'yyyy-MM-dd');
    if(check < today)
    {
        // Previous Day. show message if you want otherwise do nothing.
        // So it will be unselectable
    }
    else
    {
        // Its a right date
        // Do something
    }
  },

Comment: new versions of full calendar have explicit params for this. Don't thing this javascript is needed

Comment: https://gist.github.com/juanbrujo/c4a0a8d36fc64860f487  .I use liferay server with tomcat. I  put js file on js folder and define it in liferay-porlet.xml . <header-portlet-javascript>/js/fullCalendarDisablePrev.js</header-portlet-javascript>     but isn't working :(

Comment: minTime and maxTime have nothing to do with disabling anything. They are just to adjust the visual display in one specific view. You probably want the [validRange](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/validRange) feature for your purpose.

Comment: As can be seen in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43132961/how-to-set-maximum-and-minimum-date-range-in-fullcalendar-jquery

Comment: $('#calendar').fullCalendar({ drop Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fullCalendar is not a function. What is the problem?